# Spin and Go tips and tactics

Tags: texas-hold-em

Are there any particular tips involving playing Pokerstars spin and go games? I have been fairly successful in tournaments so far but just can't win at Spin and Go. I'm a rather tight player so when I get raised preflop by other spin and go players I don't have the heart to call 90% of the time due to j just how few chips you get in a Spin and Go game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are 3 handed, $500 stack, and starting blinds of 10/20. You are already in the Harrington yellow zone.

The value of speculative hands like 89s goes way down.  Maybe on the button to steal blinds as a backup.

You need a wider range 3 handed and you need to take a stand and call or 3 bet a re-raise with most of your range. A short stack means you need to take a stand **more** not less.  If you are folding to 90% of the re-raise that is a hole.  You should be calling or 3 bet like 50% - 70%.  Lots of charts outs on range by position and stack size.

With a wider range no need for a stone cold bluff pre-flop.

On the button size your raise small like 2.5 BB so you can more afford to call a re-raise.

From the blinds getting close to 10 BB if you have a hand to play just shove.

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the time you will be very shortstacked. Don't be afraid to shove a lot. Generally, people will call you way too tight. Use **icmizer2** and memorize some common spots. Suprisingly, you can even shove wider than what icmizer suggests in my opinion. You can get this for less than 20 bucks for a month and it is absolutely worth it.

Regularly **watch videos** on twitch and youtube for more deepstack, post-flop strategies and adapt your current strategy accordingly.

Start playing the lowest stakes and slowly move your way up.

Remember, spin & go's have insane variance. You need proper bankroll management. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man :) PS I only play Spin and Go's when I don't have the funds to enter decent tournaments.